# react redux architecting table actions and reducers

Tags: javascript, reactjs, redux, react-redux

I have server driven data being displayed in tables on multiple pages.

I currently have the following table actions

```
pageChange
pageSizeChange
sort
load
loaded
```

I have filters on some pages which need to trigger the load.

I have multiple entities which use this functionality, which will share most the above logic, but will need separate load functionality defining.

My thought was to have actions which take the table ID as a parameter, and then have a createTableReducer function which would also take this ID and would mount table nodes within entities, similarly to createModelReducer in [react-redux-form](http://davidkpiano.github.io/react-redux-form/#/api/Home?_k=va12ss)

How could I trigger the entity specific load actions from my generic actions without using something like redux saga?

I was wondering about creating a higher order component and passing it the load function but I don't think this would solve my issue. I could also call both the change action and the load action from the table component itself, but this doesn't' seem like a nice solution.

Answer (score 20):

So, this is a pretty open-ended question and possibilities for implementing this are almost limitless... but, I'll take a shot at it anyhow. This answer isn't doctrine, it's just *one* possible way to do it.

Let's start by wishing we could plop our tables wherever we want. To differentiate one table from another, all we have to do is pass a `tableId` property that links a `Table` to the corresponding data in the store.

```
<Table tableId='customers' />
<Table tableId='products' />
<Table tableId='orders' />
<Table tableId='transactions' />
```

Next, let's define a state shape to work with. Each top-level key matches a `tableId` we wish to store data for. You can make this shape be whatever you'd like, but I'm providing this so you have to do less mental visualization as I reference things in later code. You can also name the top-level `tableId` keys whatever you want, just so long as you reference them consistently.

```
{
   customers: {
     page: 0,
     sortBy: 'id',
     cols: [
       {id: 'id',         name: 'name'},
       {id: 'username',   name: 'Username'},
       {id: 'first_name', name: 'First Name'},
       {id: 'last_name',  name: 'Last Name'},
       ...
     ],
     rows: [
       {id: 1, username: 'bob', first_name: 'Bob', last_name: 'Smith', ...},
       ...
     ]
  },
  products: {
    ...
  },
  orders: {
    ...
  }
  ...
}
```

Now, let's get the hard part out of the way: the `Table` container. It's a lot to digest all at once, but don't worry, I'll break down the important bits individually.

**containers/Table.js**

```
import React from 'react';
import {connect} from 'react-redux';
import actions as * from './actions/';

const _Table = ({cols, rows, onClickSort, onClickNextPage}) => (
  <div>
    <table>
      <thead>
        <tr>
         {cols.map((col,key) => (
           <Th key={key} onClickSort={onClickSort(col.id)}>{col.name}</Th>
         )}
        </tr>
      </thead>
      <tbody>
        {rows.map((row,key) => ...}
      </tbody>
    </table>
    <button onClick={onClickNextPage}>Next Page</button>
  </div>
);

const Table = connect(
  ({table}, {tableId}) => ({    // example: if tableId = "customers" ...
    cols: table[tableId].cols,  // state.table.customers.cols
    rows: table[tableId].rows   // state.table.customers.rows
  }),
  (dispatch, {tableId}) => ({
    onClickSort: columnId => event => {
      dispatch(actions.tableSortColumn(tableId, columnId));
      // example: if user clicks 'last_name' column in customers table
      // dispatch(actions.tableSortColumn('customers', 'last_name'));
    },
    onClickNextPage: event => {
      dispatch(actions.tableNextPage(tableId))
    }
  })
)(_Table);

export default Table;
```

> **If you only learn one thing from this post, let it be this:**

The thing to notice here is that `mapStateToProps` and `mapDispatchToProps` [accepts a second argument](https://github.com/reactjs/react-redux/blob/master/docs/api.md#arguments) called `ownProps`.

```
// did you know you can pass a second arg to these functions ?
const MyContainer = connect({
  (state, ownProps) => ...
  (dispatch, ownProps) => ...
})(...);
```

In the container I wrote above, I'm destructuring each of the vars we care about.

```
// Remember how I used the container ?
// here ownProps = {tableId: "customers"}
<Table tableId="customers" />
```

Now look at how I used `connect`

```
const Table = connect(
  // mapStateToProps
  ({table}, {tableId}) => ...
    // table = state.table
    // tableId = ownProps.tableId = "customers"


  // mapDispatchToProps
  (dispatch, {tableId}) => ...
    // dispatch = dispatch
    // tableId = ownProps.tableId = "customers"
)(_Table);
```

This way, when we're creating the dispatch handlers for the underlying component, (`_Table`), we'll have the `tableId` available to us within the handler. It's actually kinda nice that the `_Table` component itself doesn't even have to concern itself with the `tableId` prop if you don't want it to.

Next notice the way the `onClickSort` functions is defined.

```
onClickSort: columnId => event => {
  dispatch(actions.tableSortColumn(tableId, columnId));
}
```

The `_Table` component passes this function to `Th` using

```
<Th key={key} onClickSort={onClickSort(col.id)}>{col.name}</Th>
```

See how it **only** sends in the `columnId` to the handler here ? Next, we'll see how `Th` is the one to send the `event`, which finally dispatches the action.

**components/Table/Th.js**

```
import React from 'react';

const Th = ({onClickSort, children}) => (
  <th>
    <a href="#sort" onClickSort={event => {
      event.preventDefault();
      onClickSort(event);
    }}>{children}</a>
  </th>
);

export default Th;
```

It's not necessary to keep the `event` if you don't want it, but I figured I'd show you how to attach it in case you wanted to utilize it for something.

Moving along ...

**actions/index.js**

Your actions file is going to look pretty standard. Notice we provide access to `tableId` in each of the table actions.

```
export const TABLE_SORT_COLUMN = 'TABLE_SORT_COLUMN';
export const TABLE_NEXT_PAGE = 'TABLE_NEXT_PAGE';

export const tableSortColumn = (tableId, columnId) => ({
  type: TABLE_SORT_COLUMN, payload: {tableId, columnId}
});

export const tableNextPage = (tableId) => ({
  type: TABLE_NEXT_PAGE, payload: {tableId}
});

...
```

Lastly, your `tableReducer` might look something like this. Again, nothing too special here. You'll do a regular `switch` on the action type and then update state accordingly. You can affect the appropriate part of the state using `action.payload.tableId`. Just remember the state shape I proposed. If you choose a different state shape, you'll have to change this code to match

```
const defaultState = {
  customers: {
    page: 0,
    sortBy: null,
    cols: [],
    rows: []
  }
};

// deep object assignment for nested objects
const tableAssign = (state, tableId, data) =>
  Object.assign({}, state, {
    [tableId]: Object.assign({}, state[tableId], data)
  });

const tableReducer = (state=defaultState, {type, payload}) => {
  switch (type) {
    case TABLE_SORT_COLUMN:
      return tableAssign(state, payload.tableId, {
        sortBy: payload.columnId
      });
    case TABLE_NEXT_PAGE:
      return tableAssign(state, payload.tableId, {
        page: state[payload.tableId].page + 1
      });
    default:
      return state;
  }
};
```

---

**Remarks:**

I'm not going to go into the async loading of the table data. Such a workflow is already nicely detailed in the redux docs: [Async Actions](http://redux.js.org/docs/advanced/AsyncActions.html). Your choice of redux-thunk, redux-promise, or redux-saga is up to you. Choose whichever you understand best! The key to implementing `TABLE_DATA_FETCH` properly is making sure you dispatch the `tableId` (along with any other parameters you need) like I did in the other `onClick*` handlers.

Comment: Hi, thanks for your answer, there are some nice concepts above ;)  One of the things I've been trying to work out the best way of doing is once the tableSort action is triggered, how to then trigger the load action, and where / how this load action should be plugged into the table

Comment: @Tom, you specifically say "without using something like redux-saga," but after learning redux-saga, I'm not sure I know how to make any other recommendation. I recently had trouble modelling the control-flow for my app and gaearon himself replied to my question nudging me to check out redux-saga. I'm really happy I took the time to understand it because it cleaned up my app tremendously.

Comment: Sure , I do like it and would like to adopt it fully soon , at present though I am using it just to handle side effects of the table actions, and with it just being used in this one place I think it is confusing so am looking to find an alternative.

Comment: I am now thinking I may be able to pass in the load action as a prop, and then call this action after dispatch in mapDispatchToProps..

Comment: All good. I might suggest you take what you can from this post and run with it for a while. Try your best to implement the fetching code using `actions.tablefetchData(tableId, itemsPerPage, page)`. redux-thunk or redux-promise should get you most of the way there. At the very least, if you run into additional trouble, your next question will be much more specific.

Comment: Hi, one thing to mention , the way you use the Object.assign in the table reducer doesn't work, https://jsfiddle.net/88z5gvwo/, I instead used icepick.merge https://github.com/aearly/icepick#user-content-mergetarget-source-associator

Comment: @Tom thanks for eagle eyes ! I updated the answer with a working solution.

Comment: @naomik This answer is really useful!
You may integrate the example with the async loading data? I read the documentation, but I can't figure out how do I handle the call to the server with all data.    For example if I order by name and then I go to page 2, how can I handle the call to the server and tell the sorting and pagination if I am in the action that handles the pagination? This part is unclear. I hope I was clear in describing the problem.